# ERROR: column "id" is of type uuid but expression is of type bytea in Hibernate 6

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using Hibernate 6. I have a column defined in a postgres database as a`uuid`.

However, I removed the type annotation for a postgres uuid because the type was removed from Hibernate 6. Now I get the following error:

```
ERROR: column "id" is of type uuid but expression is of type bytea
```

```
@Entity
public class SomeObject implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    private SomeKey id;
}
```

```
@Embeddable
public class SomeKey implements Serializable {
    private UUID id;
    private int other;
}
```

```
        SomeObject obj= new SomeObject();
        obj.setId(new SomeKey (UUID.randomUUID(),0));
        session.persist(obj);
```

Not sure how to fix. It was working before with @Type annotation.

Edit:
Seems like this also causes the same issue

```
@Basic
@JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.UUID)
private UUID id;
```

Comment: Where do you get that error? I suppose a query? You shouldn't need the type, Hibernate supports the PostgreSQL UUID column type out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

This is an incredibly hacky solution, but I was able to get it to work by creating a new PostgresUUIDType which mirrored the one from Hibernate 5.6.*.

That would get reads to work, but not writes. To fix writes, I had to also remove `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)`.

So final working code looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class SomeObject implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private SomeKey id;
}
```

```
@Embeddable
public class SomeKey implements Serializable {
    @Type(value=PostgresUUIDType.class)
    private UUID id;
    private int other;
}
```